# D3.js bar chart generate bar color on weight or value of data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi everyone please help me below is my code. so actually I getting all bar color as black what my requirement is to generate bar color dynamically with different value different color gradient don't need space in between bar just need to plot bar chart with different color on basis of data I am providing**

```js
var chartdata = [10, 21, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120,
  135, 150, 165, 180, 200, 220, 240, 270, 300, 330, 370, 410
];

var margin = {
  top: 30,
  right: 10,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 50
}

var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  width = 720 - margin.left - margin.right,
  barWidth = 40,
  barOffset = 20;

var dynamicColor;

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(chartdata)])
  .range([0, height])

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(0, chartdata.length))
  .range([0, width])

var colors = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, chartdata.length * .33, chartdata.length * .66, chartdata.length])
  .range(['#d6e9c6', '#bce8f1', '#faebcc', '#ebccd1'])

var awesome = d3.select('#bar-chart').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .style('background', '#bce8f1')
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')')
  .selectAll('rect').data(chartdata)
  .enter().append('rect')
  .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr('x', function(data, i) {
    return xScale(i);
  })
  .attr('height', 0)
  .attr('y', height)
  .on('mouseover', function(data) {
    dynamicColor = this.style.fill;
    d3.select(this)
      .style('fill', '#3c763d')
  })

.on('mouseout', function(data) {
  d3.select(this)
    .style('fill', dynamicColor)
})

awesome.transition()
  .attr('height', function(data) {
    return yScale(data);
  })
  .attr('y', function(data) {
    return height - yScale(data);
  })
  .delay(function(data, i) {
    return i * 20;
  })
  .duration(2000)
  .ease(d3.easeElastic)

var verticalGuideScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(chartdata)])
  .range([height, 0])

var vAxis = d3.axisLeft(verticalGuideScale)
  .ticks(10)

var verticalGuide = d3.select('svg').append('g')
vAxis(verticalGuide)
verticalGuide.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')')
verticalGuide.selectAll('path')
  .styles({
    fill: 'none',
    stroke: "#3c763d"
  })
verticalGuide.selectAll('line')
  .styles({
    stroke: "#3c763d"
  })

var hAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
  .ticks(chartdata.size)

var horizontalGuide = d3.select('svg').append('g')
hAxis(horizontalGuide)
horizontalGuide.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + (height + margin.top) + ')')
horizontalGuide.selectAll('path')
  .styles({
    fill: 'none',
    stroke: "#3c763d"
  })
horizontalGuide.selectAll('line')
  .styles({
    stroke: "#3c763d"
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>
<div class="someclass">
  <h2>barchart</h2>
  <div id="bar-chart">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi try with below code

```
var chartdata = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120,
  135, 150, 165, 180, 200, 220, 240, 270, 300, 330, 370, 410
];

var margin = {
  top: 30,
  right: 10,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 50
}

var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  width = 720 - margin.left - margin.right,
  barWidth = 40,
  barOffset = 20;

var dynamicColor;

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(chartdata)])
  .range([0, height])

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(0, chartdata.length))
  .range([0, width])

var colors = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, chartdata.length * .33, chartdata.length * .66, chartdata.length])
  .range(['#d6e9c6', '#bce8f1', '#faebcc', '#ebccd1'])

var awesome = d3.select('#bar-chart').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .style('background', '#bce8f1')
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')')
  .selectAll('rect').data(chartdata)
  .enter().append('rect')
  .styles({
    'fill': function(data, i) {
      return colors(i);
    },
    'stroke': '#31708f',
    'stroke-width': '1'
  })
  .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr('x', function(data, i) {
    return xScale(i);
  })
  .attr('height', 0)
  .attr('y', height)
  .on('mouseover', function(data) {
    dynamicColor = this.style.fill;
    d3.select(this)
      .style('fill', '#3c763d')
  })

.on('mouseout', function(data) {
  d3.select(this)
    .style('fill', dynamicColor)
})

awesome.transition()
  .attr('height', function(data) {
    return yScale(data);
  })
  .attr('y', function(data) {
    return height - yScale(data);
  })
  .delay(function(data, i) {
    return i * 20;
  })
  .duration(2000)
  .ease(d3.easeElastic)

var verticalGuideScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(chartdata)])
  .range([height, 0])

var vAxis = d3.axisLeft(verticalGuideScale)
  .ticks(10)

var verticalGuide = d3.select('svg').append('g')
vAxis(verticalGuide)
verticalGuide.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')')
verticalGuide.selectAll('path')
  .styles({
    fill: 'none',
    stroke: "#3c763d"
  })
verticalGuide.selectAll('line')
  .styles({
    stroke: "#3c763d"
  })

var hAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
  .ticks(chartdata.size)

var horizontalGuide = d3.select('svg').append('g')
hAxis(horizontalGuide)
horizontalGuide.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + (height + margin.top) + ')')
horizontalGuide.selectAll('path')
  .styles({
    fill: 'none',
    stroke: "#3c763d"
  })
horizontalGuide.selectAll('line')
  .styles({
    stroke: "#3c763d"
  });
```

**i just added**

```
 .styles({
    'fill': function(data, i) {
      return colors(i);
    },
    'stroke': '#31708f',
    'stroke-width': '1'
  })
```